# Datagrid Edit mode and data validation via service

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I got a `datagrid(dg)` which is bound with an observable collection of `POCO [Name(string), value(int), isReady(bool)]`

I need to let the name being editable so my `DataGrid` has `<data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>` wich contains a `TextBox`.

when committing the edit, I need to call a WCF Service to validate the name. That's what I am doing in CellEditEnded.

But when the name is not valid, how can I:

1. Display an error on the datagrid (searching a solution with ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors but can't succeed)
2. Put the cell back in edit mode.

Here's why I can't validate in the POCO:

1. `DataGrid` is in edit mode
2. By double clicking on a cell, the label containing the data becomes a `TextBox`. I'm now in edit mode
3. I insert an error. An `assynchronous validation` is launched. `DataGrid` is back in display mode
4. the `assync` is finished, I raised my error, but nothing happens (visually I mean) because `ValidatesOnNotifyDataError`s does not seems to work on label.

And more, as I know there is an error, if I enter back in edit mode, I get a really strange display telling there is 1 Error and when enterring this state, I can't get out of edit mode, whatever I do...

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)
I would recomend that you do not use the grid event to validate your data - do this on your POCO properties setter - its cleaner, easier to mantain and if you use this POCO with another control your validation will still work.

Since you need to access a service to validate the value, your best bet is to implement the interface INotifyDataErrorInfo, that allows you to make asynchronous validation, look here: http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/22/silverlight-4-and-asynchronous-validation-with-inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx and here http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/validation/asynchronous-data-validation

Comment: That was a nice and elegant idea, but it doesn't work. I edited my question to explain why.

Comment: It is nice and elegant and it does work :) - You just need to understand how. Since you know when the async call end that you have an Error, you can do something to warn the user. If you enter edit mode with an invalid value, the datagrid will not let you exit the field until you inform a valid value (maybe when you detect an invalid value you can clear that value so this do not happen). Look here a basic implementation http://dl.dropbox.com/u/427024/temp/so/INotifyDataErrorInfo/test.html
(valid Names are "" or "VALID")

Comment: How did you reach to get your label working with  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors ?

Comment: I used an DataGridTemplateColumn with a Label (not a TextBlock) with a custom style that define VisualStates for when the value is invalid... here is a basic sample, is far from complete or tested but it will give you an idea: https://github.com/leo-mck/INotifyDataErrorInfo